# JPA: Foreign key constraint on delete

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have the following relationship

```
Class UserAccount{
//Other fields
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "userAccount", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
private Set<Images> imagesShared;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "USER_LIKES", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_NAME"),   inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID"))
private Set<Images> imagesLiked;
}

Class Images{
//other fields
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "imagesLiked")
private Set<UserAccount> likes;
}
```

I get an exception after these lines

```
Hibernate: delete from IMAGES where ID=?
Hibernate: delete from COMMENTS where COMMENT_ID=?
Hibernate: delete from COMMENTS where COMMENT_ID=?
Hibernate: delete from COMMENTS where COMMENT_ID=?
Hibernate: delete from COMMENTS where COMMENT_ID=?
Hibernate: delete from COMMENTS where COMMENT_ID=?
Hibernate: delete from IMAGES where ID=?
```

Exception:

```
Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testdb`.`USER_LIKES`, CONSTRAINT `FKC6704E28B4E3D8B` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `IMAGES` (`ID`))
```

From my understanding this happens when JPA tries to remove `imagesShared`. 
I tried doing this:

```
for (Images image : userAccount.getImagesShared()){
            image.setLikes(null);
        }
em.remove(account);
```

But same error. Anyone?

**UPDATE**

When I add this line it works fine.

```
 for (Images image : userAccount.getImagesShared()){
            image.setLikes(null);
        }
userAccount.getImagesShared().clear();
em.remove(account);
```

But what is the difference between the remove operation that JPA does and what I do?

Comment: Try emptying the collection instead of making it null in the loop: image.getLikes().empty()

Comment: Yes,I have tried that, but doesn't help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of your `private Set<Images> imagesShared` or `private Set<Images> imagesLiked` must have a reference to the Image you are trying to delete.

You will have to loop through everything and remove the image reference before removing it.

EDIT :

To answer your second question.

```
 for (Images image : userAccount.getImagesShared()){
            image.setLikes(null);
        }
userAccount.getImagesShared().clear();
em.remove(account);
```

works because you are clearing the image references stored in `userAccount` by calling `userAccount.getImagesShared().clear()`

Previously what you were doing was simply removing the likes stored in that Image, not removing the images from the `userAccount` object itself.

Comment: So what I understand is you need to clear all the Image reference in the UserAccount object before the cascade remove is acted on the image  object?

Comment: Cascade works from top down... If your Image is referenced from a UserAccount it won't be deleted just because you are deleting the Image. If you delete the userAccount then it will delete the sub elements in it given there are no other references.

Answer (score 1):

The `private Set<Images> imagesLiked` has a foreign key reference to the  `IMAGES` (`ID`) so if you are trying to delete the `private Set<Images> imagesShared;` without deleting the `private Set<Images> imagesLiked;`.

So try removing the imagesLinked also

```
image.setImagesLinked(null);
```